# Get information about the Jenkins builds related to specified username

Tags: python, jenkins

I want to find all builds which started some user by his username. Is it possible to do with the help of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you could use Python, if you have access to the jenkins master.

The userId is in build.xml which is usually in your jenkins **jobs/you_job_name/builds/your_build_number/build.xml**

You could iterate over all the jobs and their builds and get the answer from there.

Comment: But I want to get information about all builds which was started bu some user, I mean when I call some url like a **builds/user_name** I'll get result where will list of builds for this user. Can I get such info?

Comment: Again, I gave you the fishing rod you should catch your own fish. :) short answer yes python + flask?

Comment: Yes, python and flask